# Can any one explain to me what is the meaning of “of its kind” and "of many a pet"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, idioms

Here is the phrase which I am reading:

> The only fully equipped centre of its kind, TANUVAS’ critical care unit has come to the rescue of many a pet
>   <sub>Source: [A go-to place to save animals in their golden hour](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/a-goto-place-to-save-animals-in-their-golden-hour/article17451206.ece)</sub>

Comment: Please consider adding the source of your sentence to your question. It might not be absolutely needed, but it's good practice anyway.

Comment: Hi @DamkerngT. this is the source http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/a-goto-place-to-save-animals-in-their-golden-hour/article17451206.ece

Comment: @DamkerngT. - You are absolutely right that it's a good practice, and sometimes it's downright necessary. Feel free the cite [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) next time you leave such a helpful comment.

Answer (score 2):

*Kind* is a noun that is synonym of *sort*.

> A group with similar characteristics, or a particular type. (*Cambridge Dictionary online*).

The sentence means that there is no other centre as well equipped as TANUVAS’ critical care unit. As it says [further down in the article](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-national/tp-tamilnadu/a-goto-place-to-save-animals-in-their-golden-hour/article17451055.ece), it's "the best".

*Of many a* means "a lot of". "Many a" is archaic, you would not use it in everyday conversation.

Comment: *You would not use "many a" generally in **regular** conversation.  English is all about flow, and sometimes somebody might use it (sounds like the OP's article is pretty modern).  Also, if you wanted to be formal, you may use "many a" (more likely in writing than speech).

Comment: I don't talk to my friends the same way as I would their parents... I'm definitely less formal in some situations.  I always thought it was colloquial?  Yes, you are likely to find it in poetry, when you're scraping for that extra syllable!

Comment: +1 Though I wonder which the OP was confused by more, between *of* and *many a* in *of many a pet*.

Comment: @marcellothearcane "not" was missing in my comment...  should read : I would not say "everyday conversation" is "formal speech". It is not written English either. You're more likely to find it in poetry. It is by no means colloquial, quite the opposite, a [good answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/25558/12918) on ELU about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Of its kind
```

This means, in this case, 'which can provide the service that it does'.

In general it means 'which has its particular or similar characteristics, attritubutes or facilities.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/of_its_kind

```
Of many a pet
```

This means 'of many pets'.

Comment: beat me by 8 seconds!  [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25555/usage-of-many-vs-many-a) article explains the difference between 'many a' versus 'many'

Comment: Ha ha! They don't call me speedy Gonzalez.... at all actually 